# Make a DropDownList Distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Database Table:

```
|ID|      |Athlete|        |Sport|
 1     Jacoby Ellsbury     Baseball
 2     Dustin Pedroia      Baseball
 3      Kobe Bryant        Basketball
 4      Lebron James       Basketball
 5     Patrick Kane         Hockey
 6     Sidney Crosby        Hockey
```

I want to create a *dropdownlist* of only the `Sport` property on my Create action

What I have tried:

```
ViewBag.Sport = new SelectList(db.AthleteTable.Distinct(), "ID", "Sport");
```

Or:

```
ViewBag.Sport = new SelectList(db.AthleteTable, "ID", "Sport").Distinct();
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sport, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Sport", null, "-- Select Sport --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sport, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

This renders my dropdownlist but the values repeat so:

```
Baseball
Baseball
Basketball
Basketball
Hockey
Hockey
```

What I want:

```
Baseball
Basketball
Hockey
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

the reason why my table is like this is because I can create other dropdownlists and separate each Athlete by Sport like so:

```
List<SelectListItem> lstAthletes = new List<SelectListItem>();

        using(var context = new ConnectionString())
        {
            List<AthleteTable> lstAthletes = context.AthleteTable.ToList();
            var groups = lstAthletes.GroupBy(x => x.Sport);
            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                var slg = new SelectListGroup() { Name = group.Key };

                foreach(AthleteTable athlete in group)
                {
                    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = athlete.Athlete, Value = athlete.ID.ToString(), Group = slg };
                    lstAthletes.Add(item);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is `Sport` not a separate tale in your data set?  You may want to consider denormalizing your data,which would make this (and possibly other tasks) cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy`:

```
var distinctSports = db.AthleteTable.GroupBy(a => a.Sport).Select(g => g.First());
ViewBag.Sport = new SelectList(distinctSports, "ID", "Sport");
```

However, it's strange that you select the sports from the athlete table and map the athlete-id to the sport-name which are completely unrelated because it's the athlete-id not the sport-id.

Normally you should have a `Sport`-table and a foreign-key to it in your athlete-table. Then you could select from that and all sports would be unique.

Comment: This isn't my real code.. I am creating example off of the top of my head, to get my point across

Comment: Also when I ran your example, I had to change the `g.First` to `g.FirstOrDefault` but still works!

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: why you had to change it to `FirstOrDefault`? It's not possible that a group doesn't exist/is empty after `GroupBy`.